# Is there a way to enable support in Debezium Postgres Connector to capture Composite Types columns?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using the Debezium Postgres connector, and I'm finding that the connector doesn't capture columns that are composite types, or arrays of composite types. Is there some configuration involved in enabling this or is this not supported? I'm not seeing the definition of the composite type in the schema portion of the debezium message nor the composite type itself in the payload. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Custom types and thus composite types are not supported yet. There's a [feature request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-920) about enum types already, perhaps you can file one for composite types.

If you feel adventureous, you could try and use the [include.unknown.datatypes](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/#connector-properties) connector option, which will propagate the raw representation as the connector obtains it from the WAL. But you should keep in mind that consumers deal with a PG-internal representation that way which might change down the road.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention: of course any help with implementing custom type support would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I tried the suggested "include.unknown.datatypes" option, but it doesn't seem to work during snapshot. The column type in my case is ltree array. I see WARN Postgres|postgres1|records-snapshot-producer Unexpected JDBC BINARY value for field ancestor_ids with schema Schema{BYTES}: class=class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList, value=... [io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresValueConverter] and null value is returned. This is using 0.9.5.Final

Comment: Can you please file a bug report at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ? This should definitely work during snapshotting and streaming. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Gunnar. I've created https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1335. I also noticed that UUID ARRAY typed columns cause trouble. Not sure if this is related to "include.unknown.datatypes" being set to true. I see this in the connector log 2019-06-04 00:31:59,059 WARN   Postgres|postgres1|records-snapshot-producer  No converter found for column cms_6ce80a49_7854_41cc_9fe7_388a25788d5b.cms_app_bundle.depends_on of type _uuid. The column will not be part of change events for that table.   [io.debezium.relational.TableSchemaBuilder]